# Is the infinite integer set order isomorphic to its infinite proper subset

Tags: order-theory

It is quite obvious that the statement is true, but is there any theorem to show that the infinite integer set is order isomorphic to its infinite proper subset? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by isomorphism between sets? Isomorphisms are defined between sets which have a certain structure; a group, a ring, a vector space. Second of all, what do you mean by "its infinite proper subset"? The integers have many infinite proper subsets.

Comment: @YuvalGat The structure you ask about is  $(S,\le)$. This is clear, since the OP said "order isomorphic". It happens sometimes that we get posts here from people with limited English-language skills - "its infinite subset" meant "any infinite subset of the integers".

Comment: @YuvalGat Sorry about the confusion. I'm asking about the structure $(S,\leq)$, and I mean any infinite subset of the integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Obvious" or not, it's not true for subsets of the *integers*. For example $\Bbb N$ is an infinite subset of $\Bbb Z$ which is not order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

It *is* true for sets of *natural numbers*, which is perhaps what you meant to say. This is so trivial it's not going to be a **Theorem** with a name:

> > **Unnamed Theorem.** If $S\subset\Bbb N$ is infinite then $S$ is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb N$.

**Proof.** Define $f:\Bbb N\to S$ recursively, by $f(0)=$ the smallest element of $S$ and $f(n+1)=$ the smallest element of $S$ larger than $f(n)$. Then it's not hard to show that $f$ is an order isomorphism. (One detail: for each $n\in\Bbb N$ you can show by induction on $m$ that $n<m$ implies $f(n)<f(m)$,)